# Yocto - how to create a repository with project specific changes

Tags: git, yocto

I am a new software developer and currently working on a project to build customized Linux distribution for an embedded product. I have checkout the Yocto krogoth branch and working on it. I have now created a meta-bsp layer with is specific to my board. Now I want to create a repository and check in the changes I have made.

What is the best way in this case to create and maintain a repo. Since the Yocto project itself is a git repository and I have a meta-bsp layer specific for my board. Should I use a git submodules? Any idea on this would be helpful. When there is an update from Yocto for new releases I would like to switch to it in future.

Comment: Do you have the ability to push features branches to the Yocto repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the repo tool which I felt is better than git submodules for the use case.The Freescale Yocto project is also maintained by using the repo which can be used for reference: http://freescale.github.io/#download

Need to create an empty git repository and a default xml file which contains the information about where to fetch the git repositories required for the project.

I found the following link to be useful:
http://www.instructables.com/id/Using-Googles-repo-command-in-your-own-projects/

If others found any better way than this to maintain an Yocto project please let me know